# SQL SERVER Triggers interfere in MS-Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, triggers

I tried a question few days ago without any answer. I try to clarify my problem.

**Context :**

- MS-ACCESS application linked to the SQL SERVER database
- 2 linked tables : Orders and OrdersLines
- A trigger in SQL SERVER on OrdersLines to calculate turnover (quantity x unit price)
- In MS-access a form (frmOrders) with a subFrom linked with the idOrder field

**The problem :**

1. When I add a new record in frmOrders and fill in the Orders and OrdesLines fields => No problem
2. Then, if I modify any value of any field of the Orders table on the current record => Access error "Data has been modified. Another user has modified this record....". That's the trigger I think
3. The data re-entry worked after the error message in point 2
4. I add a me.requery command to the afterupdate event in the edited field in point 2, to avoid error message.
5. the me.requery command in point 4 unfortunately moves to another record in frmOrders and I have to close the form and reload it to reach the correct record.
6. I try RsClone = Me.recordset.clone and RsClone.findfirst commands without success (frmOrders is in addNew mode)
7. When I modify the record after reopening it, the Me.Requery does not cause the result of point 5. It reload the correct record which is editable with no error message.

**My Question**

How to avoid the record movement of point 5 ?

Comment: "A trigger in SQL SERVER on OrdersLines to calculate turnover (quantity x unit price)" why not a materialised view?

Comment: Please edit the existing question instead of reposting it repeatedly

Comment: *"I tried a question few days ago without any answer."* So is this the same problem in your prior [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718694/sql-server-triggers-ms-access-forms), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730163/sql-server-ms-access-triggers) questions?

Comment: It also looks like you posted your question as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784493/2029983). Answers are for answers, not questions.

Comment: I guess the real question is why you have the trigger. Why not just use a view to calculate the total on the fly